# Поиск и замена текста между тегами в PHP

Tags: php

Существует текст, внутри которого может быть такая разметка:

```
<ul>
элемент1<br />
элемент2<br />
элемент3<br />
элемент4<br />
элемент5
</ul>
```

На `PHP` в текте нужно обнаружить все теги `<ul></ul>` и обернуть в них строки в `<li></li>`, чтобы получилось:

```
<ul>
<li>элемент1</li>
<li>элемент2</li>
<li>элемент3</li>
<li>элемент4</li>
<li>элемент5</li>
</ul>
```

Текст внутри `<ul></ul>` получилось найти через эту регулярку:

```
'#<ul>(.+?)</ul>#is'
```

А обернуть элементы списка можно так:

```
preg_replace('<br />', '</li><li>', 'Teкст');
```

Проблема в том, что не получается объеденить эти две конструкции, чтобы оборачивать элементы списка только лишь внутри `<ul></ul>`.

Comment: Проблема в том, что используется некорректный инструмент. Для парсинга xml есть достаточно инструментов и это точно не регулярки.

Comment: @u_mulder это не XML, а посты в админке. Авторы пишут так и нужно исправлять.

Comment: HTML - это очевидно разновидность XML.

Comment: `str_replace(['<ul>', '</ul>', '<br />'], ['<ul><li>', '</li></ul>', '</li><li>'], $text)` - без регулярок, просто поиск и замена

Comment: @InDevX <br /> может быть не только в конце потенцильного пункта списка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант решения с использованием [preg_replace_callback()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
<?php

$i = <<< EOT
<ul>
элемент1<br />
элемент2<br />
элемент3<br />
элемент4<br />
элемент5
</ul>

<ul>
элемент11<br />
элемент12<br />
элемент13<br />
элемент14<br />
элемент15
</ul>
EOT;
echo
    preg_replace_callback(
        "~<ul>(.+?)</ul>~ims",
        function ($m) {
            return
                "<ul>" .
                implode(
                    "",
                    array_map(
                        function ($itm) {
                            return "<li>" . strip_tags($itm) . "</li>";
                        },
                        array_filter(
                            preg_split("~\r?\n~", $m[1])
                        )
                    )
                ) .
                "</ul>";
        },
        $i
    );
?>
```

[Песочница](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/11b71041931e1c7133914aa7a2ac8663b8f44d3d)